# Connection Refused Error Trying to Import ElasticSearch Model through Rake on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, tire, bonsai-elasticsearch

For some reason, on heroku it will not allow me to import models (this is for the Bonsai ElasticSearch add-on).  It's just showing connection refused.  I'm not sure how to resolve this. I've searched the internet and I can't find anything that will even hint me in the right direction to solve this. I checked to make sure the server was up and manually created the index with curl. Do the initializers get launched when running a rake task?

I set the  elasticsearch url in the config/initializers/bonsai.rb file:

config/initializers/bonsai.rb

```
if Rails.env == 'production'
  ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] = ENV['BONSAI_URL']
end
```

Gemfile snippet

```
# Used for elastic search
gem 'elasticsearch-model', github: 'elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', github: 'elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'multi_json'
gem 'json'
```

Error

```
heroku run rake environment elasticsearch:import:all DIR=app/models
Running `rake environment elasticsearch:import:all DIR=app/models` attached to terminal... up, run.5751
[IMPORT] Loading models from: app/models
[IMPORT] Processing model: Firm...
rake aborted!
Connection refused - connect(2)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:39:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:21:in `block in perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:102:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:81:in `bulk'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:78:in `block in import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:88:in `block in __find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:125:in `find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model/proxy.rb:80:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:86:in `__find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:77:in `import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model.rb:113:in `import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-rails/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-rails/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb:99:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-rails/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb:82:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/elasticsearch-rails-26a3ba246968/elasticsearch-rails/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb:82:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => elasticsearch:import:model
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**by the way can someone create an 'elasticsearch-rails' tag since its the upcoming replacement for Tire**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch Rails does not use the same mechanism as Tire to set its URL in production on Heroku.  To have this work correctly with Bonsai search, you have to have a different url specification.  Fortunately a guy has made a gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/bonsai-elasticsearch-rails) to eliminate the needless, mandatory creation of a initializer by everyone.

Simply add this gem to your gem file under your production group. The version may be subject to change since it's so new:

```
gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails', '~> 0.0.4'
```

If you're more curious about what this gem actually does, the entire source is below:

```
require "bonsai/elasticsearch/rails/version"

puts "Starting up a new ElasticSearch client with #{ENV['BONSAI_URL']}"
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL']
```

I know, simple right...